# Using a ForEach statement to query and set the time zone on multiple hosts

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm trying to build a PowerShell script to set the time zone on multiple computers, whilst I have a GPO set to do this also, this only applies after a reboot. I would therefore like something that is quick and easy to push out to many machines.

```
$computers = Get-Content "\\RedactedFilePath.txt"
$TimeZone = "Azerbaijan Standard Time"

Foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Write-Host "Setting Time zone on $Computers" -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host "Checking current time zone information" -ForegroundColor Green
    invoke-command -cn $computers {tzutil /g}
    Write-Host "Setting event time zone to $TimeZone" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    invoke-command -cn $computers {tzutil /s “Azerbaijan Standard Time”}
    Write-Host "Checking time zone information post change" -ForegroundColor Green
    invoke-command -cn $computers {tzutil /g}
}
```

Now, when run this works, but it runs the sequence repeats itself for the number of computers in the script rather that running individually for each computer. Does anyone know how I might separate this out so that it runs the sequence indivdually for each computer?
[Script running multiple instances of the same command rather than running them separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1cwk.png)
TIA,
James

Comment: `invoke-command -cn $computer {tzutil /g}` as in `$computer` without **s**

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. All it needed was a second pair of eyes to spot my blindingly obvious mistake! Ha

Answer (score 0):

Posted as comment, but for clarity will post it as answer. You are parsing an array (`$computers`) to `-ComputerName` switch. What it needs is `$computer` (without "**s**")

```
$computers = Get-Content "\\RedactedFilePath.txt"
$TimeZone = "Azerbaijan Standard Time"

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Write-Host "Setting Time zone on $computer" -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host "Checking current time zone information" -ForegroundColor Green
    invoke-command -cn $computer {tzutil /g}
    Write-Host "Setting event time zone to $TimeZone" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    invoke-command -cn $computer {tzutil /s "Azerbaijan Standard Time"}
    Write-Host "Checking time zone information post change" -ForegroundColor Green
    invoke-command -cn $computer {tzutil /g}
}
```

PS. Keep in mind that while powershell will be easy on you when it comes to character casing - remember that PS is an exception when it comes to ignoring case :)